# How to redirect my blog to another url in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.9

I have redirected my blog  from `blog/my-blog-post` to `blog/post/my-blog-post`
and it gives me a 404 error in magento 1.9.

Comment: what are the rewrite rules that you have placed?? in which location you made these changes? what is your server? Does your server has cache kind stuff??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from htaccessin a simple way. Add below code in htaccess at bottom:

Redirect 301 /blog/my-blog-post to http://www.domainname.com/blog/post/my-blog-post

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento's default 301 URL Redirect functionality for that.

https://stuntcoders.com/magento-tutorials/magento-catalog/how-to-create-301-redirect-from-magento-admin-panel/